# Conditionally inherit color in beamer

Tags: beamer, color, itemize

I'd like to change the `fg` color of the item symbol in `beamer`. In `normal text` it should be, e.g. yellow but inside an `exampleblock` or `alertblock` it should inherit from the `block title.fg`. Here is a NWE with the default definition of the item color.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{item}{parent=local structure}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item xyz
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{block}{abc}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item xyz
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
  \begin{exampleblock}{abc}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item xyz
    \end{itemize}
  \end{exampleblock}
  \begin{alertblock}{abc}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item xyz
    \end{itemize}
  \end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a color setting command to the `begin` templates for the environments `block`, `exampleblock` and `alertblock` as follows:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=block title.fg}}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=block title example.fg}}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=block title alterted.fg}}{}
```

assuming you wanted these to match colour of the respective block title.  These will then overrule any global value you have set for the item colour in these environments.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=yellow}

\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=block title.fg}}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=block title example.fg}}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=block title alerted.fg}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item xyz
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{block}{abc}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item xyz
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
  \begin{exampleblock}{abc}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item xyz
    \end{itemize}
  \end{exampleblock}
  \begin{alertblock}{abc}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item xyz
    \end{itemize}
  \end{alertblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```